# Given the url, how to load an image and then transform it into a tf.tensor data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am new to frontend and javascript. Now I am writing a CNN-based web application. To load an image from the given url, and then feed the image into a CNN, I tried to write the following codes:

```
async function getImage() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://www.google.com/favicon.ico';
  var output = tf.browser.fromPixels(img);
  return output;
}
```

Unfortunately it didn't work ;(

How do I load the image and transform it into a tf.tensor? Could somebody help me achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tensor has to be created once the image has completed to be loaded

```
async function getImage() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://www.google.com/favicon.ico';

  img.onload = () => {
  var output = tf.browser.fromPixels(img);
  return output;
  }

}
```

Comment: This is returning undefined for me. Any ideas why. I tried adding     img.crossOrigin ="Anonymous" but with no luck.

Comment: Could you please ask your question in a new thread ?

Comment: Getting this error: `Error: pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels() must be either an HTMLVideoElement, HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, ImageData in browser, or OffscreenCanvas, ImageData in webworker or {data: Uint32 Array, width: number, height: number}, but was Image`