# Tensorflow.js prediction result doesn't change

Tags: angularjs, tensorflow, ionic-framework, tensorflow.js

I trained my model with [Google Teachable Machines (Image)](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/image) and inclueded the model into my Ionic Angular app. I loaded the model successfully and used the camera preview for predicting the class which is shown in the image from the camera.
The picture which is displayed in the canvas changes properly but the predict()-method returns the same result for every call.

```
import * as tmImage from '@teachablemachine/image';
...

async startPrediction() {
   this.model = await tmImage.load(this.modelURL, this.metadataURL);
   this.maxPredictions = this.model.getTotalClasses();
   console.log('classes: ' + this.maxPredictions); //works properly

   requestAnimationFrame(() => {
     this.loop();
   });
}


async loop() {
   const imageAsBase64 = await this.cameraPreview.takeSnapshot({ quality: 60 });
   const canvas = document.getElementById('output') as HTMLImageElement;
   //image changes properly, I checked it with a canvas output
   canvas.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageAsBase64; 

   const prediction = await this.model.predict(canvas);
   for (let i = 0; i < this.maxPredictions; i++) {
     const classPrediction =
       prediction[i].className + ': ' + prediction[i].probability.toFixed(2);
      //probability doesn't change, even if I hold the camera close over a trained image
   }

   requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.loop();
   });
}
```

The prediction result is e.g.: class1 = 0.34, class2 = 0.66 but doesn't change.
I hope you could help me to find my bug, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has probably not yet been loaded before you are calling the prediction model. It has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482902/given-the-url-how-to-load-an-image-and-then-transform-it-into-a-tf-tensor-data/58581581#58581581) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758368/convert-base64-image-to-tensor/61761058#61761058)

```
function load(url){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     canvas.src = url
     canvas.onload = () => {
          resolve(canvas)
        }   
   })
}

await load(base64Data)
// then the image can be used for prediction
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this makes sens but it seems that the onload() is never called, any idea about that?

Comment: It is called under the hood when the image has completed to load

Comment: But it isn't called, do I need a element in my html for that?

Comment: Did you use the  `await` ? Because the `await` will wait until the promised is resolved. And if the promise is resolved, that means that `onload` was called

Comment: Yes I'm using the await, the problem is that the onload() is never called so the promise isn't resolved

Comment: The `src` needs to be set after the `onload` function. I edited the answer